# Given that B has rational co-ordinates and A , B are equidistant from H. I need to find B(h,k).

Tags: coordinate-systems

I am given two points $A(3,5)$ and $H (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5})$ and a third point $B(h,k)$ . Given that 
$B$ has rational co-ordinates and A , B are equidistant from H. I need to find $B(h,k)$.

What I tried :

$AH^2 = BH^2$

$h^2 + k^2  - 2\sqrt{2}(h-3) - 2\sqrt{5}(k-5)-34=0$     ------------>(1)

In the book , it is given that since $B(h,k)$ are rational so $h-3=0 , k-5=0$

I didn't understand this step . Eq(1) gives the locus of possible points B. So what does $h-3=0$
and $k-5=0$ got to do with $(h,k)$ being rational?

Answer (score 0):

The sum of a (nonzero) rational number and an irrational number is never zero. Therefore, the expression labeled as equation one is only zero if the irrational terms are each themselves zero. This yields $2\sqrt{2}(h-3)=0$ and $-2\sqrt{5}(k-5)=0$, from which the result follows.

Comment: $ -2\sqrt{2}(h-3)$ , $ - 2\sqrt{5}(k-5)$ will always be irrational for all $(h,k)$ except when $(h,k=3,5)$  . But Eq(1) is of a circle so there will be infinte $(h,k)$  that satisfies the equation. This contradicts your theory that sum of a non zero rational number and an irrational number is never zero